# how to return a arrayList from a spinner adapter

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-spinner

I have the folloiwng spinner adapter for my customer spinner. In additon to different text for each item i hav different font and background colors. I dictate this by passing an `arrayList<ArrayList<String>>` which indicates the colors and text values for each item - inner arraylist reps an item.

Now i want to get the selected items array list back to calling class by getting its id and pulling out the correct arrayList but im not sure how to construct this method's parameters. something like `spinner.getItemDetails_Arraylist(...);`

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>{ 
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    private Context c;
    public SpinnerAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> objectList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objectList);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = context;
        this.list =objectList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_custom, parent, false);
        TextView textView_item=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_teamName);

        //Pull team details from the object at position
        ArrayList<String> itemDetails = list.get(position);  
        String itemName = itemDetails.get(0);
        String itemAbbreviation = itemDetails.get(1);
        String iteme_primaryColor = itemDetails.get(2);
        String item_secondaryColor = itemDetails.get(3);

        //Update the spinner item controls
        textView_team.setText(teamName);
        textView_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item_primaryColor));
        textView_item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(item_secondaryColor));

        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `setOnItemSelectedListener` to your spinner and get the view of the selected position then you can extract your list

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {
        TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_teamName);

        int color_id = tv.getCurrentTextColor(); // get textColor 

        ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) tv.getBackground();
        int backcolor_id = cd.getColor(); // get background color

        String text = tv.getText().toString(); // get the text
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

**Another solution:**
If you still have the original ArrayList you can use the same `setOnItemSelectedListener` to get the position of the selected item then you can get the small list of it from the original list

```
ArrayList<String> selected_item = new ArrayList<String>();

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {
        selected_item = originalList.get(position);
        // where original list is your main ArrayList<ArrayList>
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Comment: many thx. How would i do it from a button click event ie get what the selected item of a spinner is when another unrelated button on the screen is clicked?

Comment: @Fearghal you're welcome. You can use `int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();` that returns the selected item's position :)